# Continuous mapping theorem counterexample

Tags: stochastic-processes

let g be a continuous function.
Then from the continuous mapping theorem
We have the following result.
If xt converges to x* wp1
as t goes to infinity then
g(xt) converges to g(x*) wp1

Now suppose g is only piecewise continuous. Do we have an example
Which demonstrates the conclusion
Of the continuous mapping theorem
Does not hold when g is not continuous?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. 
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Think an example such that $g$ is discontinuous at $x^*$ with positive probability...

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful!